# Cryptocurrency exchanges that have swift code

Tags: exchanges

Is there some cryptocurrency exchange that has SWIFT code?
If a cryptocurrency exchange doesn't have SWIFT code, I cannot send dollars from my bank to it.
Thanks.

Comment: Both Binance and Huobi don't seem to have swift code.